# The perfect form after modal verbs

Tags: tense, modal-verbs

Which are correct?

Who do you think was the murderer in the story?

1) I think Ben would be the murderer.

2) I think Ben would have been the murderer.

3) Ben would be the murderer.

4) Ben would have been the murderer.

I feel puzzled with the tense problem of modal verbs. Could you please help me out?

Comment: I don't understand why you try to use _would_. Why don't you follow the temporal scheme of the question (think - was) i.e. _I think Ben was definitely not the murderer._

Comment: Here "would" is use to express probability and likelihood, namely, I guess Ben was the murderer.

Comment: I understand your aim. Nevertheless, _would_ sounds strange to my ear and I would prefer _could_. If I change _would_ for _could_ I'd say 2 and 4 are appropriate because the question asks _who was the murderer?_. Both are actually the same. 1 and 3 could be used if the question asked _who is the murderer?_. This would be more appropriate anyway because the murderer _is_ still the murderer even if his deed lies in the past. There is no need to use a past tense.

Comment: Thanks. Here I try to assume a situation that A is telling an imaginary story to B and the murderer is not known yet. Which one is more appropriate? who is/was the murderer?

Comment: Having thought a second time about it I don't see any crucial difference between _is_ and _was_. It's just that _is_ focuses on the present (_Who is the person, who has commited the murder?_) while _was_ focuses on the past (_Who was the person commiting the murder._).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've learnt a lot from your comments.